# Excel matching stock s with order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data with the stock number and its' specification and another set of data with the order and the requested specification, is there a way to use excel to automatically matching the stock to the order?

| Stock ID | Specifcation |
| --- | --- |
| 212345 | 144PRMP |
| 212346 | 144PRMP |
| 212347 | 123ELTP |
| 212348 | 123ELTP |
| 212349 | 144BASI |
| 212350 | 144BASI |
| 212351 | 177BASI |
| 212352 | 177BASI |
| 212353 | 123BASI |
| 212354 | 123BASI |

| Order ID | Specifcation |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | 144PRMP |
| A124 | 144PRMP |
| A125 | 144PRMP |
| A126 | 144PRMP |
| A127 | 177BASI |
| A128 | 177BASI |

Result I'm trying to achieve:

| Order ID | Stock ID | Specifcation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 212345 | 144PRMP |
| A124 | 212346 | 144PRMP |
| A125 | N/A | 144PRMP |
| A126 | N/A | 144PRMP |
| A127 | 212351 | 177BASI |
| A128 | 212352 | 177BASI |
| A129 | 212347 | 123ELTP |
| A130 | 212353 | 123BASI |

I've tried using PowerQuery but no luck to achieving what I want, would appreciate the help from here, thanks!

Comment: Index() with match() and lots of examples on here.

Comment: `XLOOKUP()` may a good choice.

Comment: There isn't any logic that explains why 212345 matches to A123. e.g. why not A124? This logic needs to be explained before you can find a solution. It's not clear where you got stuck with Power Query - it would be my choice if I were working on this problem. You will need to show a lot more of your work.

Comment: In this example, 212345 could be matched to both A123 or A124 as they were the same specification, so no specific logic as long as there's no duplication. As long as the same stock would not be allocated to 2 or more orders would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The formula below

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,10^LOG10($B$2:$B$11=I2)*ROW($B$2:$B$11),COUNTIF($I$2:I2,I2)))
```

will result in `#NUM!` errors where there is a mis-match

[image: screenshot illustrating proposed formula]

so you will have to include it in an `IFERROR()` function if you really want `N/A` instead.